# Issues With Afreechart - LineChart Horizontal scrolling - Android

Tags: android, jfreechart

I have created Line chart with Afreechart library.
In that I have 3 categories having 20 values.
I have added graph in linear layout...
The problem is that graph shows all value in one view and margin between values is little.
I want to enable Horizontal scrolling as it has vertical scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the zoom feature in the context menu?